# Bound mismatch error in case of argument being passed for enum type in abstract class

Tags: java, enums

```
public class HttpMethodMessageReader extends      AbstractEnumMessageReader<HttpMethod>{}
```

Here argument HttpMethod gives error as “Bound mismatch: The type HttpMethod is not valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum> of the type AbstractEnumMessageReader”

For Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEnumMessageReader<E extends Enum<E>> {
     public       AbstractEnumMessageReader(MessageReader      defaultReader, Class<E> e){
Super(defaultReader, new EnumMap(e));
}


public class HttpMethodMessageReader extends AbstractEnumMessageReader<HttpMethod>{}
```

Here argument HttpMethod gives error as “Bound mismatch: The type HttpMethod is not valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Enum> of the type AbstractEnumMessageReader”

For Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEnumMessageReader<E extends Enum<E>> {
     public      AbstractEnumMessageReader(MessageReader      defaultReader, Class<E> e){
     Super(defaultReader, new EnumMap(e));
}
```

Suggest a way to resolve this bound mismatch error